# Android: manage more touches in a general View

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

In my app I want manage many touches inside the same view in this way:

I want obtain the exact number of finger that are over this view, that is, if lay a finger my total should be 1, if I lay a second finger the total should be 2, and etc. for 3,4,5... (until my device support its max number of touches).
It's ok but I want in real time also the total if I remove a finger from the screen, that is, if I layed 2 fingers over the screen ok the total is 2, but if I remove a finger the total should became 1.

I create this code but it doesn't work fine.

```
touch_view = (View)findViewById(R.id.touch_view);

        touch_view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                int action = event.getAction();

                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ){

                    touches++;
                    Log.i("", "touches "+ touches);
                    Log.i("", "action down");

                }
                else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN){
                    touches++;
                    Log.i("", "touches "+ touches);
                    Log.i("", "pointer down");
                }
                else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP){
                    touches--;
                    Log.i("", "touches " + touches);
                    Log.i("", "pointer up");
                }
                else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                    touches--;
                    Log.i("", "touches " + touches);
                    Log.i("", "action up");
                }
                else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL){

                    Log.i("", "cancel");
                }
                else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER){

                    Log.i("", "action over enter");
                }
                else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT){

                    Log.i("", "action over exit");
                }
                else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){

                    Log.i("", "action outside");
                }
                else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK){

                    Log.i("", "index mask");
                }

                if (action != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    Log.i("","pointer count"+event.getPointerCount());
                    Log.i("","action type" +event.getAction());
                }
```

I notice that my count "touches" doesn't work well... and sometimes my log "event.getAction()" give me a strange number (261, 262...517,518...) what type of action are these numbers?
Can you help me?

Comment: Check constant here identify action : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_CANCEL

Comment: Finally I decided to check constant... if I'm not in ACTION_DOWN or in ACTION_UP and not even in ACTION_MOVE; I check if the constant is even or odd... if it's even I reduce the "touches" value and if it's odd I increment it... I answer to my question to show how I make it...

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
touch_view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                int action = event.getAction();

                if (action != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

                    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ){

                        current_touches = 1;
                        Log.i("", "current touches " + current_touches);
                    }
                    else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                        current_touches = 0;
                        Log.i("", "current touches " + current_touches);
                    }

                    else{

                        int action_code = event.getAction();

                        if (action_code%2 == 0){

                            if (current_touches != 0)
                                current_touches--;
                        }
                        else
                            current_touches++;

                        Log.i("", "current touches " + current_touches);


                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```